# How to handle errors in serverless

Tags: rest, error-handling, serverless-framework

i'm doing this:

```
context.fail({
            message: "Invalid Token!",
            code: app.error["010"].code,
        });
```

and when i call api from postman, it is returning me:

```
{ 
  "errorMessage": "[object Object]"
}
```

even i'm not sending any key named `errorMessage`

My question is, am i using correct way to return error
if yes, why it is behaving like this
if no, what is the correct way to handling error in serverless

I'll be thankful.

Comment: Are you using lambda or lambda-proxy to hook up your api endpoint to labmda function?

Comment: i dont know about lambda proxy, i just created an account on aws and a user in it and i use `sls deploy` command to push my code on aws

Comment: What version of serverless are you using?

Comment: `C:\Users\aDmIn>sls -v`
`1.0.0-rc.2`

Comment: If you upgrade to 1.0 you will be using `lambdaProxy` integration. You can then return custom headers and `body` html really easy. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return an error object and it should work.
Also use callback instead of context to return an error(that's the default behavior now, context.fail works just for legacy support)

`callback(new Error('Your message'))`